# User Define Role and Right on Membership Provider on MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, membership, provider

Dear All,
I am using the membership provider of MVC framework, Now i want to implement the Role and Right on My project, All the Role and Right is available on database so how can i implement the Role and Right? is there is any built in function which can i use? also i am using the Ado .net Data Entity Framework..

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly, you have to annotate your Controller class or ActionResult with the Authorize attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Domain Admins", Users="testuser")]
public class TestController : Controller {

}
```

Then as long as your membership provider is setup you should be good to go.

It may be worth mentioning that you can always check if a user is in a role with the following code.

```
User.IsInRole("Domain Admins");
```

If your using MVC2 then the default project template makes it easy. You should check out the AccountController and AccountModels in a default MVC2 template.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a custom role provider:

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/17/CreateCustomRoleProviderASPNETRolePermissionsSecurity.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx